# Wrap every function or class method in a Python module by default without decorating every one

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I have some code from which I want to get an email whenever it runs into an exception like this.

```
try:
    f(**kwargs)
except Exception as e:
    # email me the environment
```

I know that Python decorators can work for this, like:

```
@check_error
def f()
@check_error
def g()
```

What if I want every code in my module be wrapped by default?  Like 
`def f()` without the `@check_error`, but I still want to be able to achieve this.
Ideally, the solution should apply for both functions and class methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can introspect modules, so assuming `module` is the module for which you want to decorate all functions you could do something like this:

```
import inspect
for name, f in inspect.getmembers(module, inspect.isfunction):
    setattr(module, name, check_error(f))
```

You could even do this in the current module by using `sys.modules[__name__]` for `module`